# Which is better select 1 vs select * to check the existence of record?

Tags: sql-server

Which is better in below cases.

1.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 3)
BEGIN
    -------
END
```

Vs

2.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE ID = 3)
BEGIN
    -------
END
```

Or both are same?

Comment: `select` terms in `exists` subqueries are ignored, making this choice a matter of preference.

Comment: It doesn't matter. both have the same performance

Comment: I never use SELECT 1 because it looks ugly and tells me that the coder concerned too much about performance without knowing how it really works.

Comment: SELECT * will fetch all the columns but SELECT 1 will not, so this is not performance matter?

Comment: You forgot option 3 which could be `SELECT column FROM TABLE...` which is probably what I would do as `SELECT *` is often evil.

Comment: Nothing is selected at all, therefore it doesn't matter. Choose whatever you find most readable. I prefer `1`, but you could also use `*` or `NULL` or `'grfertgrtghwegerg'
`.

Comment: @RajKumar It doesn't matter which one you choose, the SQL engine treats them both the same.

Comment: @DavidG..If ID column has Non-Clustered index then SELECT ID vs SELECT * will be different in case of performance?

Comment: @RajKumar: SQL-Server optimizes queries. Since the columns from the table are not needed to check if a row exists, they are not queried at all.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly..That's means if that record set is stored in 2 data pages then SELECT * also will not hit both pages to read the data in case of exists query?

Comment: @RajKumar Don't know how to explain this any other way! SQL Server internally will look at the query and treat them all exactly the same as they are inside the `EXISTS()` block. It won't go and get any rows or columns.

Comment: SQL Server will evaluate the * while generating the execution plan. Then it will essentially ignore it in the context of EXISTS.  So, you may save a micro second during planning, unless the plan is cached, but the execution it self will be Identical.

Comment: There is a good answer to this question on DBA StackExchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159413/exists-select-1-vs-exists-select-one-or-the-other

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`EXISTS` will check if any record exists in a set. so if you are making a SELECT from 1 million records or you are making a SELECT from 1 record(let say using TOP 1), they will have same result and same performance and even same execution plan.(why?) Because exists will not waits until 1 million record scan complete(or 1 record scan complete). Whenever it finds a record in a set, it will be return the result as TRUE(There is no matter in this case you are using * or column name both will have same performance result).

```
USE pubs
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.titleauthor)
PRINT 'a'

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.titleauthor)
PRINT 'b'
```

below is the execution plan for these queries(as I have Screen size problem, I have cropped it's image)
[image]
[image]

But this scenario and performance and even execution plan will be completly change, when you are using queries as follow(I do not know why should use this query!):

```
USE pubs
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.titleauthor)
PRINT 'a'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 )
PRINT 'b'
```

in this scenario, as SQL Server does not need to perform any scan operation in second query, then the execution plan will be changed as follow:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @RajKumar please hold the "The Answer is Useful" button firmly ;-)

Comment: I thought part of the question was to compare `SELECT * FROM table` and `SELECT 1 FROM table`. A question that seems to have been asked and answered more times than I've had breakfast.