# MSQL trigger to insert record in second table based on update of specific field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a simple trigger in Microsoft SQL Server. It involves two tables (sorry for the non-standard syntax):

```
customer {
  customerno (integer)
  comm_preference (varchar(1))
  email (varchar(255))
  }

email_sent {
  customerno (integer)
  email (varchar(255))
  date (datetime)
}
```

Valid values for customer.comm_preference are M, E, B (mobile, email, both).  I need a trigger that if the value is changed to E or B, a record with the customer.customerno, customer.email, and today's date are inserted into email_sent.

So far, my efforts have been a total wash. Can someone help me?

Comment: what version you are using of MS SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it will insert a new record in email_sent table while record insert with 'E' or 'B' or value changed to 'E' or 'B'

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg
   ON  customer
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM inserted WHERE comm_preference IN ('E', 'B')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO email_sent 
            SELECT customerno, email, GETDATE() from inserted
        END        

END
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. A little note: `SELECT  1` is the same as `SELECT   *`

Comment: I mean `IF EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM inserted WHERE comm_preference IN ('E', 'B')` is simply the same as `IF EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM inserted WHERE comm_preference IN ('E', 'B')`. Many people write 1 just thinking that * will select all rows. But it the same. For me * in this case is more readable.

Comment: When you select * inside IF EXISTS, there is no difference. SQL SERVER does't fetch any data in IF EXISTS statement. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798285/which-is-better-select-1-vs-select-to-check-the-existence-of-record

Comment: @Piyush that is not true. When using select * in an exists it does NOT return every column. It just checks to see if there are rows that meet the criteria. The actual performance is identical in either case. It comes down to a matter of coding preference.

Comment: Never mind the minor issue of whether `SELECT 1` is better than `SELECT *` or not, the logic in this answer is wrong. Triggers fire once per action, not once per row, so what this trigger is actually doing is "if any updated rows have comm_preference = E or B (regardless of whether it has been changed) then insert all updated rows into the email table" - I don't think this is what the original poster wants. If you want to test this try `UPDATE customer SET email = email` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomer_Update ON dbo.customer FOR UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(comm_preference)
            BEGIN
                INSERT  dbo.email_sent
                        ( customerno
                        ,email
                        ,date
                        )
                        SELECT  i.customerno
                               ,i.email
                               ,GETDATE()
                        FROM    inserted i
                        INNER JOIN deleted d
                        ON      i.customerno = d.customerno
                        WHERE   d.comm_preference NOT IN ( 'E', 'B' ) AND
                                i.comm_preference IN ( 'E', 'B' )
            END
    END
GO
```

Regards,

Rhys